# Show matrix is element in eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=A$.

> a) Let $E_{1}(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n} | Ax=x \}$: let $E_{0}(A)=\{{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} | Ax=0\}}$. Let $x$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Show that $Ax \in E_{1}(A)$ and $x-Ax \in E_{0}(A)$
>
> b) Show that if A is diagonalizable, then rank$(A)=tr(A)$

There are the last two problems in my problem set that have me absolutely stumped. Could someone be kind enough to provide solutions and a brief explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem?  Theorems that come to mind, dead-ends that you've found so-far?

Comment: Also, it is not clear what the connection is between the question you've asked and the title you've put, or even what the title is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Part a) is simply a matter of applying definitions.  What can we say about $A(Ax)$?  What about $A(x - Ax)$? Remember that $A^2 = A$.

For part b), what could the eigenvalues of $A$ be?  If $A$ is diagonalizable, it is similar to a diagonal matrix.  What does that matrix look like?  How do we compute its rank?  Remember that two similar matrices have the same rank and trace.